# How can I display my input php on the screen?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach, colors

I have to make an assignment where I have to process the following things:
Make an array "color" and fill it with 10 color names.
Create a script that displays the contents of the array in a table.
Create a script that tests an entered color for presence within the color array, and returns whether or not it is. My problem now is that I do not know how to return the correct answer in the input. This is my code:

```
<?php
// different colors:
$color = array(
    '#99ed5c' => 'green',
    '#9c9991' => 'grey',
    '#17ffb6' => 'blue',
    '#a21647' => 'purple',
    '#fbd8c1' => 'light-pink',
    '#1f33a3' => 'dark-blue',
    '#7e0509' => 'red',
    '#f7d856' => 'yellow',
    '#3b0b1b' => 'violet',
    '#de4405' => 'orange'
);

function build_table($color){
    // start table
    $html = '<table>';

    // header row
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach($color as $key=>$value){
        $html .= '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '</th>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';

    // data rows
    foreach( $color as $key=>$value) {
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '</td>';
        $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }

    // finish table and return it

    $html .= '</table>';
    return $html;
}

echo build_table($color);



echo "fill in a color: <input type='text' name='kleur'>";
echo "<input type='submit'> <br>";



if (in_array("green", $color))
{
    echo "Match found";
}
else
{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to put it in this field? `<input type='text' name='kleur'>`

Comment: Yes. when I press the submit button it must show the image if the match is found or if the match is not found.

Comment: If you are trying to get the submitted value then you have include the text field in a form like this `echo "<form method='post'>fill in a color: <input type='text' name='kleur'>";
echo "<input type='submit'></form> <br>";



if (in_array($_POST['kleur'], $color))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got most of it right.

In order to process the user input, you will need to use form processing. that is submitting the from from the client side to the server side, [Read more info here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

So you would need to do something like:

```
<?php
// different colors:
$color = array(
    '#99ed5c' => 'green',
    '#9c9991' => 'grey',
    '#17ffb6' => 'blue',
    '#a21647' => 'purple',
    '#fbd8c1' => 'light-pink',
    '#1f33a3' => 'dark-blue',
    '#7e0509' => 'red',
    '#f7d856' => 'yellow',
    '#3b0b1b' => 'violet',
    '#de4405' => 'orange'
);

function build_table($color)
{
    // start table
    $html = '<table>';

    // header row
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($color as $key => $value) {
        $html .= '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '</th>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';

    // data rows
    foreach ($color as $key => $value) {
        $html .= '<tr>';
        $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . '</td>';
        $html .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    }

    // finish table and return it

    $html .= '</table>';
    return $html;
}

echo build_table($color);
?>


    fill in a color:
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type='text' name='kleur'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'> <br>
    </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['kleur'])) {
        echo "You left the color input blank.";
    } else {
        $inputColor = $_POST['kleur'];
        if (in_array($inputColor, $color)) {
            echo "Match found";
        } else {
            echo "Match not found";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Note that you can close the PHP tag to print out HTML normally without the need of echo'ing.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, this is it! I knew I need to put a form into it. But didn't know how to connect it with the fact that it needed to display to my screen. and I thought I should put the input in an echo. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of an input, simply set the `value` parameter like so:

```
<input type='text' name='kleur' value='<?= $value ?>'>
```

or in your case

```
echo "fill in a color: <input type='text' name='kleur' value='" . $color . "'>";
```